# span characters that matches a string

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am trying to make an incasesensitive check if some text in a list mathes a variable (pattern) and if it does wrap spans around the same word.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
var pattern = 'lor';
var filter = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');//create regexp
$('ul li').each(function() {
    var spanResult = $(this).text().match(filter);//match html with filter
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(spanResult) >= 0)
    {
        $(this).text().replace(spanResult, '<span>'+spanResult+'</span>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes:

- Use `html` instead of `text`
- `if(spanResult)` is a simpler condition if the match is true

Here is a jsBin to [span characters that match a string](http://jsbin.com/UterIVu/1/edit?js,output). I added some CSS to change the spans to red so you can see them.

```
var pattern = 'lor';
var filter = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');//create regexp
$('li').each(function() {
    var spanResult = $(this).text().match(filter);//match html with filter
    if (spanResult)
    {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(spanResult, '<span>'+spanResult+'</span>'));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:contains` and then a callback of the `.html()`

```
$("ul li:contains('" + pattern + "')").html(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    return text.replace(pattern, "<span>" + pattern + "</span>";
});
```

Comment: I thought about that method, but :contains is case sensitive.